# Application Load Balancer with ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I am trying to configure load-balancing for Fargate ECS. My understanding is that there are at least two target groups. One target group gets created along with the Application Load Balancer, and one target group gets created along with the ECS service.

My containers are running their service on TCP port 5000. I want the load balancer only to expose HTTPS over the regular 443 port, and redirect HTTP to HTTPS, or if that is difficult, just drop HTTP.

I see that Listeners allows specifying a whole bunch of things. However, I am confused by the target group created with the service. It - the `IP` -type group, listens on port 80. Whether I select HTTP or HTTPS during the service creation/configuration.

My containers never get any traffic. I enabled load-balancer logging, it seems that the balancer does not understand what I want it to do. There `"forward" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-"`in the log at end of every request.

I ran `aws elbv2 describe-target-groups` to get the definitions.

```
{
  "TargetGroups": [
    {
        "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:505963211XXX:targetgroup/ecs-fargate-api-service-tg/1ebb89754b34d072",
        "TargetGroupName": "ecs-fargate-api-service-tg",
        "Protocol": "HTTPS",
        "Port": 80,
        "VpcId": "vpc-e623dd9b",
        "HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTPS",
        "HealthCheckPort": "traffic-port",
        "HealthCheckEnabled": true,
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 5,
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "HealthCheckPath": "/cookie-policy",
        "Matcher": {
            "HttpCode": "200"
        },
        "LoadBalancerArns": [
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:505963211XXX:loadbalancer/app/node-api-lb/f5e512a2678688f5"
        ],
        "TargetType": "ip"
    },
    {
        "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:505963211XXX:targetgroup/node-api-tg/7544b53ab1720e0d",
        "TargetGroupName": "node-api-tg",
        "Protocol": "HTTPS",
        "Port": 443,
        "VpcId": "vpc-e623dd9b",
        "HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTPS",
        "HealthCheckPort": "traffic-port",
        "HealthCheckEnabled": true,
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 300,
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount": 5,
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 2,
        "HealthCheckPath": "/cookie-policy",
        "Matcher": {
            "HttpCode": "200"
        },
        "LoadBalancerArns": [
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:505963211XXX:loadbalancer/app/node-api-lb/f5e512a2678688f5"
        ],
        "TargetType": "instance"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I go about setting up an application load-balancer for ECS Fargate to have HTTPS on the outside and route everything to the correct container PORT?

Comment: If you have only 1 ECS service, you should have 1 ALB. Not sure why you have two. ALso, your `"Protocol": "HTTPS",` which means that your containers operate in HTTPS, they have proper SSL certicates? Or you meant HTTP here as usually is done?

Comment: I wrote why there are two target groups. You cannot create an application load balancer without specifying the target group. Can you? The SSL certificate needs to given to the ALB, which it pulls from ACM. The containers do not need them.

Comment: Off course you can have 1 TG. Not sure how did you create two of them. You also specified `HealthCheckProtocol": "HTTPS` which means that your ECS service will always be unhealthy if your containers use HTTP only.

Comment: Change `"Protocol": "HTTPS",` to `"Protocol": "HTTP",`, and set healtchcecks to HTTP if your containers use HTTP. Also you don't need second TG with port 443 as you don't use HTTPS in your containers.

Comment: How could one have one target group when one is created along with the router - `instance` and one with the ECS service - `ip`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what is your setup. Could you please clarify what is router instance? The ECS fargate setup is generally very easy - 1 TG for 1 service. Maybe you could provide some screenshot which would better illustrate your setup?

Comment: Yes, we must create a NEW target group for the new service. Hence, we cannot choose the target group, which was used/necessary to make the application load balancer. Right? I don't see an option to choose an existing group, only to make a new one. Maybe, via CloudFormation, one could specify something else. From UI, I don't see anything except what I see.

Comment: Give me few minutes, will try to make some screenshots.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the comments, the screenshots.

### First create ALB

You can create your TG when you create your ALB (ALB is called **dddd** in my example), or beforehand. ALso, I named my target group **my-tg-for-fargate**. I used port 80 (you probably need 5000) as I used [nginxdemos/hello](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/hello) as my container. Make sure to create **IP target type**, not instance. Fargete will not work with instance TGs, explaining why you can't see them in ECS console when creating your ECS service.

[image]

### Create ECS Fargate service

When you create your Fargate service in ECS console, you will have option to choose **existing ALB** (in my case `dddd`) and **existing target group** (in my case called `my-tg-for-fargate`. You don't need to create **second tg**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I only have `create new` as the option. Yet, my load-balancer is doing `instance` routing. Perhaps, I should just drop it and do IP routing straight away. Let me try.

Comment: @IgorShmukler Oh of course. Fargate requires IP, not instance. If you create instance TGs, then they will never work with Fargate, explaining why you can't see them.

Comment: @IgorShmukler I will add requirement of IP TGs to the answer.

Comment: I tried with `IP`. It is better. I too was able to the pre-existing target group. Now, my logs show at the and `"forward" "-" "-" "172.31.6.35:5000" "-" "-" "-"` instead of just dashes. Plus, it does change in round-robin fashion. However, something is still not working. I looked at the security groups, but don't see anything. My containers are still unreachable, including for probes. Hence, after a grace period expires, they get deregistered. I configured targets to use HTTP, and left HTTPS on the ALB listener. Still, this is another story. The load balancer appears to be better. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to create an ALB first with zero assigned targets, and then create the Fargate instance and attach it to it... why does it have to be in that order? You can't just assign an existing application to a new load balancer without completely destroying your application instance?

Comment: How do you know what IP addresses to put in the Target Group if they are dynamically assigned by Fargate?

Comment: @TimothyPulliam AWS will manage that. Its one of the properties of how load balancers work with ECS.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Your answer solved my problem regarding with ALB.